# Making a shared class in swift

Tags: swift

In swift, is there anyway I can create a shared class? That is, say there is a class called Value:

```
class Value{
  var a = 0
}
```

I want to use this class to be shared among different object instances.
For example,

```
class Main{
  func main(){
    print(Value.a)
    Value.a++
  }
}

class OtherClass{
  func otherMain(){
    print(Value.a)
    Value.a++
  }
}


let main = Main()
let other = OtherClass()
//I want this call to print 0
main.main()
//I want this call to print 1
other.otherMain()
```

I tried static on var a, but then it won't let me do arithmetics such as addition... But it is working if I change the Value into static instead of class. I thought only difference between struct and class was either variable type or reference type...

I'll appreciate to any help. Thanks

Comment: why don't you just create a global variable `var a: Int = 0`?

Comment: I am working on a large project which contains many swift files. So i want to have one separate class to handle one type of variables, and want the class to be used something like a table to share its data to other instances.

Comment: You can use Singleton pattern.

Comment: It seems your desired architecture will be very fragile.

Comment: Sulthan - why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about what you want to do, unfortunately, is not to do it at all. It seems that the architecture you're designing is quite fragile and two independent classes shouldn't depend on a shared object state and if they do, they should be related via class inheritance or protocols.

A better solution would be:

```
class MyClass {
    static var a = 0
}

class SubclassA: MyClass {
     func someFunc() {
         print(self.dynamicType.a)
         self.dynamicType.a += 1
     }
}

class SubclassB: MyClass {
    func otherFunc() {
        print(self.dynamicType.a)
    }
}
```

There's a few reasons you should do it this way, over your previous solution:

1. Your shared state can stay private to those two classes. No one outside of those classes can or should modify that value.
2. Singleton patterns while sometimes useful, have a bunch of problems. [This article](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/singletons/) explains it better than I can.

You have to think of your application and your code architecture as a state machine, moving from one state to another. The goal is to write code that's reusable, modular, generic, and has as little state as possible. The more stateless your code, the better. That's the whole idea behind platforms like ReactJS and ReactiveCocoa; they help simplify that application state.

What you might be looking for is data persistence, something like Realm or CoreData, where you persist data to disk and then you can read it back at a later time as needed. Imagine for example that instead of an `Int` your shared state was an array of `UIImages`. With the singleton pattern, you're keeping those images in memory at all times. What if the list grows to be 200 or 300 in length? Then you have memory issues.

Comment: Okay, I see the point. But my two classes are not independent so I assume inheritance was what I needed. In your code, subClassA/B inherit MyClass? So should it be SubClassA/B: MyClass? where did the dynamicType come from?

Comment: Sorry I fixed my typo. dynamicType refers to the class instances since `a` is a static var, not an instance variable. If the classes aren't related but they share the same data, then maybe rethink your data design.

Comment: I don't agree that this would be an improvement. Variables shouldn't be directly incremented like this, from another class. I would be much better to make the counter private and declare a function that will do the increment. That will make code much more readable.

Comment: I agree, that's essentially what I'm saying. I was just trying to keep my code example to @hikki's as I could.